# I found a unexpected line in my scatterplot, how can I extract all the data near the line for further analysis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is about filesize and the time cost dealing with the file.

When I drew the point plot I got the below result:

```
ggplot(data,aes(filesize,time))+geom_point()
```

[image]
You can see there are 2 lines in the plot.

How can I extract all the data near the line for further analysis?

Any advice for what to learn? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are there any other variables in your data? Just wondering whether the lines represent, for example, particular filetypes that have a linear relationship between filesize and time to read.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could provide a sample of your data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good next step would be to identify those ratios that seem more common, to make it easier to isolate those observations.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(time_per_size = time/file_size) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time_per_size)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 50) # 30 bins is default, fiddle to see what value captures the predominant ratios most cleanly
```

Using @PavoDive's sample data, for instance, we can look at the ratios using this process, and use `plotly` to look at the spikes interactively, seeing that they are around 1.5 and 3.

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  mutate(time_per_size = y/x) %>%
  filter(time_per_size < 10) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time_per_size)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 300) 
plotly::ggplotly(.Last.value)
```

[image]

Comment: Great idea. `geom_density` and an adequate zoom can show the bimodality that will give the slopes of the two lines seen

Comment: Good idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @heds1 that there's probably some underlying relationship between your outcome and [at least] a third variable, wether it's know to you or not.

See the following example with dummy data:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# try to mimic your data in the x axis. Include some random types
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(x = rbeta(3000, shape1 = 1.8, shape2 = 10), type = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 3000, TRUE))

# introduce a couple lines:
dt[type == "A", y := 3*x]
dt[type == "C", y := 1.5*x]

# and add some "white noise":
dt[!type %chin% c("A", "C"), y := abs(rnorm(.N, .5, .25))]

# see what you have:
plot(dt$x, dt$y)

# now see the light:
ggplot(dt, aes(x, y, colour = type))+geom_point()
```

[image]

[image]